# I can call my function in java bean but not using get and set

Tags: xpages

I have created a simple bean using this example from Per

http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/creating-your-first-managed-bean-for-xpages.html

And I can access the bean using

**helloWorld.setSomeVariable("test")** and

get the value using **helloWorld.getSomeVariable()**

But when I try it using EL language it doesn't work
**helloWorld.SomeVariable**

I get an error that SomeVariable doesn't exists in helloWorld

I'm probably doing some simple error, but I can't see what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem is that EL is likely case-sensitive the bean-style name of the property is "someVariable". Beans assume that you're using camel-case for the method names, so EL downcases the first letter after "set" and "get" for their translation.

Answer (score 2):

EL seems to be case sensitive in my regards and your property is defined as someVariable and not SomeVariable. have you tried helloWorld.someVariable.